# Passing data from a view controller to tabbarcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, segue

Suppose i've a login view controller, login view controller has a segue to the tabbarviewcontroller, tabbarviewcontroller has four controllers. I want to pass data to the all tabbar controllers simultaneously from that login view controller. How can i achieve this thing ?

Comment: Use prepare for segue method to achieve this.

Comment: No, we can't achieve this thing with prepare for segue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new subclass of UITabBarController, say ParentTabBarController.
2. Then in your storyboard, set the class for your TabBarController to ParentTabBarController from the Identity Inspector panel.
3. In your ParentTabBarController.h add a @property for whatever data you want to pass. Something like:

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *data;
   ```
4. When you segue from your login view to the TabBarView, pass the data in the prepare for segue method.

   ```
   ParentTabBarController *pTBVC = [segue destinationViewController];
   pTBVC.data = @"Hello";
   ```
5. In any of your tabbar controllers, you can access the parent TabBarController's data by

   ```
   ParentTabBarController *parent = ((ParentTabBarController *)self.parentViewController);
   NSString *data = parent.data;
   ```